# Greenscreen with gradient color mask

Tags: greenscreen

I am testing the video editor "videopad" and I use an eyedropper tool to pick a pixel that defines the greenscreen color which will be used overall the image to mask out the background.

However, can I define multiple eyedropper points, resulting in a greenscreen color that varies depending on where in the image you are?

The question extends to any video editing software.

## edit

Can I just take a photo of the background before I put myself there and use the photo as greenscreen mask?

Answer (score 1):

In Adobe Premiere, and other professional level video editors, it is possible to specify a tolerance for the color that you would like to remove with the chroma key operation. Apple Photo Booth allows you to take a picture and then use that matte to create transparency behind the subject, but you probably won't find this functionality in a basic editor such as videopad. It is possible to do what you're trying to do in Premiere, After Effects, Davinci Resolve, Lightworks, AVID, Final Cut X, and other video editing applications that support layered effects.

Comment: I too would recommend you use Premiere, After Effects, or better yet, yet more complicated, nuke.

Comment: At the moment, I am stacking multiple green screen effects above each other with different colors. It seems ok, but I am not convinced.

Comment: I am still getting salad in my hair however.